# Pom.xml downloading unmentioned dependencies

Tags: maven

I have a simple `pom.xml` which have only JUnit dependency and exec-maven-plugin.
But when I say "`mvn install`" I see *lot* of dependencies downloading.

Are this mandatory dependencies by maven?

I am listing a few here :

```
ClassWorlds
Commons-logging-api
log4j
backport-util-concurrent
```

Answer (score 2):

> Are this mandatory dependencies by maven

Yes, those are [transitive dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

> This allows you to avoid needing to discover and specify the libraries that your own dependencies require, and including them automatically

See "[Resolving conflicts using the dependency tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)"

> A project's dependency tree can be expanded to display dependency conflicts. For example, to find out why Commons Collections 2.0 is being used by the Maven Dependency Plugin, we can execute the following in the project's directory:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-collections
```